# How to change Spinner datepicker color? - Android Studio

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, datepicker

I've been trying for more than half an hour to change the default date picker color to a color I want, but I can't, I've searched on internet forums, but I can't find a solution that solves my problem.

This is my datepicker:

[image]

This is more or less the result I want to get:

[image]

I made the datepicker in xml, and I want it to stay in xml anyway

```
<DatePicker
                android:id="@+id/date_picker"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:datePickerMode="spinner"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                style="@style/RYZZE_DATE_PICKER"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:calendarViewShown="false"/>
```

style:

```
    <style name="RYZZE_DATE_PICKER">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ff00ff</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlNormal">#ff00ff</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#ff00ff</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.

```
          <DatePicker
                android:id="@+id/date_picker"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:datePickerMode="spinner"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:theme="@style/RYZZE_DATE_PICKER"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:calendarViewShown="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `style` to  `android:theme` in `DatePicker`.

as following:

```
<DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/date_picker"
        android:theme="@style/RYZZE_DATE_PICKER"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:datePickerMode="spinner"
        />
```

To change the horizontal bars color you need to change `colorControlNormal` & to change date text color you need to change `textColorPrimary` as following.

```
<style name="RYZZE_DATE_PICKER">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#00796B</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlNormal">#FBC02D</item>
    </style>
```

Following is the result:

[image: datepickercustom]

Comment: can i change the background color also?